# How to find a way that items with the same names wont collide with each other when left join tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have been looking around for answers for countless hrs and could not find much.I am making a food project and I was wondering if there is a way to prevent 2 items with the same name from colliding each other with their 2nd table.To make things clear I have 1 table which is

```
  CREATE TABLE cuisine (id int,dish_name varchar(32));

 //2nd table   CREATE TABLE ingrediant (id int,dish_name varchar(32),ingrediant);
```

I was wondering if lets say 2 people posted dish_name = pizza with different ingrediants,when i left join how would the tables know which one to join because the only thing that are matching is the dish_name.

I know i could add the ingrediants to the first table but lets say i am adding up to 50 ingrediants and other items it is too much stuff.

An example i can use is Ebay.
If 2 people post items with the exact same name,when the item is clicked how does it know which info it is for.Hope it is clear

Answer (score 2):

If you would model your relations correctly, you don't have that problem.

You would have to define a foreign key in the 2nd table, and the foreign key would have to refer to the primary key (or at least some other ***uniquely*** indexed field or combination of fields) in the 1st table. If you plan on using `dish_name` as a foreign key in the 2nd table, that would necessarily mean that `dish_name` would have to be unique in the 1st table.

This is probably a bad idea, so it's better to create a  `dish_id` foreign key column in your 2nd table and get rid of the `dish_name` column.

Comment: So would i have to reset all the ids for them to match?

Comment: Reset what IDs? I'm just saying that your use case can be modeled using a standard one-to-many relation. Probably good to do some research into that.